# SQLAlchemy creating a backref on a single table inheritance subclass?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a backref in a Single table inheritance situation, where one of the subclassed objects have a mixin that declares the relationship (`HasFooMixin`), but this results in the following issue:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'bar' on relationship 'ImplementedBase.foos': property of that name exists on mapper 'mapped class Foo->foos'`

I thought maybe the name 'bar' was used soemwhere else, but regardless of what I name it, the same error will be generated. The error seems to be due to the fact that there's already a backref with that name, but I cant find any in all of my codebase, and regardless of what I name it, it throws the same error.
Any idea how to solve this? Basically I want a two-way reference from bar --> foos and from foo --> bars, (but only for the polymorphic class ImplementedBase if possible)

Below are the model details.

```
def BaseClass(db.Model):
    type = db.Column(db.Text, default="base")
    ...

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity' : 'base',
        'polymorphic_on' : type
   }

def ImplementedBase(BaseClass, HasFooMixin):
     __mapper_args__ = {
         'polymorphic_identity': 'implementedbase'
     }

def HasFooMixin(object):
    
    @declared_attr
    def foos(cls)
        return cls.__table__.c.get('foos', db.relationship('Foo', secondary=mtm_foo_bar, backref="bar"))
```

```
#Table for MTM mapping Foo <---> Bar
mtm_foo_bar = db.Table('associate_foo_bar',
      db.Model.metadata,
      db.Column("foo_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("foo.id")),
      db.Column("bar_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("bar.id"))
      )
```

Comment: Note: I managed to remove the exception by using `backref=cls.__name__.lower()` however, I dont know what that will evaluate to? Is `cls` the class implementin the mixin?